# Xcode Version Editor - How to navigate through the changes?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode5

In the built-in version editor view of Xcode 4 and 5, when it shows the differences between two revisions, how do you jump from one changes to another?

I'm looking for something like the Cmd+Down/Cmd+Up shortcut keys of Araxis Merge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are already in the Version Editor:

1. In the center gutter between the left and right sides, click a revision highlight (blue area) to select it
2. Use the Up/Down arrow keys to navigate through the changes

If you are NOT already in the Version Editor do this:

1. Open the file with the changes you want to compare
2. Select the version editor viewing mode
3. Click the timeline button to select which revisions of the file you want to compare then click the timeline button again to dismiss the timeline
4. In the center gutter between the left and right sides, click a revision highlight (blue area) to select it
5. Use the Up/Down arrow keys to navigate through the changes

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Because I don't see the two buttons you are talking about.

Comment: I may have been confusing the arrows shown next to your files jump list for the next/prev buttons for similar buttons in Visual Studio, but I seem to remember being able to move next/prev last time I used the version editor.

I don't have access to my Mac at present, but I'll see if I can't figure it out once I'm back home and post an update.

Comment: Yeah, [here's the doc that describes what I was talking about.](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/100-The_Text_Editor/text_editor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002679-SW1) May not work in the version editor though, but this would be why I remembered being able to go back/forward between changes. If you scroll to the top of the doc you will see a diagram pointing out which buttons it is talking about. [This page](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-tips-and-tricks-tips-1-to-10.html) also describes that behavior I was talking about in Tip #6

Comment: Sorry I didn't see earlier that you had updated your answer with a working one (you should have posted a new answer instead). Tested OK on Xcode 4.4, thanks!

Comment: For people migrating from Perforce, this is equivalent to P4Diff's Command-1/2

Comment: In Xcode 7 (maybe earlier too), you can also use the keyboard for the selected change's pop-up menu items: press the Delete key to "Discard change" and the space bar to toggle "Don't commit".

Answer (score 9):

Thuggish Nuggets' answer is correct. To state it clearly, if you are in the Version Editor already:

Just click on the blue area in the middle gutter between the left and right sides. It will become "selected" (blue selection lines will appear top and bottom). Don't click on the little numbered button, but in the space around it.

Then you can arrow up and down (no command keys).

Not the most obvious thing... and not documented.

Comment: Yes you're right it works! Though I don't know why I wasn't able before. Oh ok I see... he completely changed his answer a couple of months later, and I didn't get notified. Thanks for pointing me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Next Change: `Control` + `\`
Previous Change: `Shift` + `Control` + `\`