# Xcode: Keyboard shortcuts for navigating changes in the commit view?

Tags: xcode, version-control, keyboard-shortcuts

When committing files to an SCM in Xcode it brings up its Version Editor with a Comparison View (showing the diffs for each file). If you click in the gutter between files you can quickly navigate between changes using the up & down arrow keys. However, you can't easily move to the next file using the keyboard (as far as I know). It's very tedious to have to use the mouse to click on each file, then click in the gutter, use the keyboard to move between changes and then click on the next file.

Does anyone know of a way to navigate between files in this view using just the keyboard?

I've done some searching & looked through Xcode's Key Bindings preferences but I can't find anything.

Comment: I also have this puzzle. I use Cmd-[ and Cmd-] to switch between files when using Cornerstone. I think if Xcode has such shortcut, it will be more convenient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Version Editor - How to navigate through the changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336857/xcode-version-editor-how-to-navigate-through-the-changes)

Comment: Not a duplicate as explained in my comment below.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit clunky, but you can press `Cmd-Shift-J` to go to the current file in the Project navigator, then use the up and down arrows to select different files. From there you can press `Cmd-J, Return` to put the cursor into the editor view.

Comment: `Cmd-Shift-J` doesn’t do anything in the source control commit view.